# Why can I access my server when I have: Warning: Identity file .ssh/key-file not accessible

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Why can I still connect to my server when the keys I am using are clearly not accessible?

From my PC, to connect to the server:

```
ssh -l myLogin -i .ssh/key-file <SERVER_IP>
```

I have tried this in these 2 configurations :

- key-file doesn't exists on my PC, and key-file.pub doesn't exist on the server
- key-file doesn't exists on my PC, but key-file.pub content is in the `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server

Both times, I get the following message, but I am still connected to the server:

```
Warning: Identity file .ssh/key-file not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

Note: I have already properly used this same PC to connect to the same server, using another proper key that I deleted locally

Is there a bad configuration on my server that allows connections without proper authentication? Or might there be any sort of cache on my PC that remembers how to access the server?

### SSH in verbose

In verbose mode (when adding `-v`), SSH gives more information:

```
Warning: Identity file .ssh/key-file not accessible: No such file or directory.

...

debug1: Will attempt key: localLogin@localLogin-laptop-ubuntu RSA SHA256:0DH/97OKekTIjdeuc2jO2Ixig9VVTpB7morVj2/GVJw agent
debug1: Will attempt key: localLogin@localLogin-laptop-ubuntu RSA SHA256:6l0joGtcoJv2yvia82zAtXK8PqBLQkesOOwDaCutc20 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/localLogin/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/localLogin/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/localLogin/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/localLogin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/localLogin/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/localLogin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/localLogin/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: localLogin@localLogin-laptop-ubuntu RSA SHA256:0DH/97OKekTIjdeuc2jO2Ixig9VVTpB7morVj2/GVJw agent
debug1: Server accepts key: localLogin@localLogin-laptop-ubuntu RSA SHA256:0DH/97OKekTIjdeuc2jO2Ixig9VVTpB7morVj2/GVJw agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <SERVER_IP> ([<SERVER_IP>]:22).

...
```

As we can see, the `Offering public key` mentions a key that I had just deleted from my local PC, but was still in ssh agent's cachge, and was still valid for the server. After logging out and on again to my local machine, everything went back to normal. Thanks @michael-hampton

Comment: It used a different key? Check the verbose output.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I updated my question with the resulting output. I suppose this has something to do with the part saying "Will attempt key: ..."?

Comment: EDIT: yes that seems to be it. ```localLogin-laptop-ubuntu``` is the name of the only valid key that was on the server and correctly used in the past. But I removed it from my local ```.ssh``` directory, and it still seems to be used as a fallback. Is that it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ssh key you say you removed from your local filesystem is still being used because your ssh agent has cached it and is providing it when you try to log in to the remote host.

You can just log out of your local system and log back in, and the ssh agent will also restart and forget your old key.

Comment: You're right. I had just deleted my previous key without logging off... Thank you for your help.